# One React NavLink fails to load the HTML - Others work fine

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is my main entry point for App and all the links work fine except for Commercial where nothing shows in the page at all, and there is no error? so I have no idea what the issue is. The other links for Client, Covid, etc all work 100% fine. I dont know how Commercial is different to the other components.

How does one go about debugging this? there are no errors, I just get a blank page for Commercial witn no html.

I am pretty new to React.

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './header.css';
import './footer.css';
import Header from './header';
import Footer from './footer';
import Body from './body';
import ClientPage from '../client-page'
import CovidPage from '../covid-page'
import Commercial from '../commercial'
import CarpetFloorPage from '../carpetfloor-page'


class App extends Component { 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header></Header>
        <Switch>          
          <Route exact path='/' component={Body} />          
          <Route path='/clients' component={ClientPage} />
          <Route path='/covid' component={CovidPage} />
          <Route path='/commerical' component={Commercial} />       
          <Route path='/carpet-floor' component={CarpetFloorPage} /> 
        </Switch>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

For example the carpet floor component looks like this and works fine..

```
import React from "react";

const CarpetFloorPage = () => (
    <div>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="floorclean-background soft-corner">
                <div className="d-flex flex-column marketing-header soft-corner">
                    <h2 className="text-center center-item">Carpet &amp; Floor Cleaning</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="p-3">
                <p>Effective cleaning is proven to prolong the life of carpet and upholstery. At <strong>White Tiger Cleaning&nbsp;</strong>&nbsp;we know the importance of cleaning and maintaining carpets. We can ensure the shortest drying times, therefore we are always able to accommodate your business requirements.</p>
                <p>Hard floor cleaning carried out on a regular basis will also preserve the quality of your floors.</p>
                <p>Here at White Tiger Cleaning we also offer our clients a routine maintenance plan. This ensures that your carpets and floors always look as good as new.</p>
                <h3>Our Carpet Cleaning Services Include:</h3>
                <ul className="list-unstyled">
                    <li><i className="fa fa-check" />&nbsp;Commercial Deep Carpet and Floor Cleaning</li>
                    <li><i className="fa fa-check" />&nbsp;Domestic Carpet &amp; Upholstery Cleaning</li>
                </ul><img className="img-fluid border rounded pulse animated" src="assets/img/floor-clean-after.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

);


export default CarpetFloorPage;
```

All the links are called from the header here... There are still links to html files as I am in the process of changing these to nav links.

```
import logo from '../assets/img/white-tiger-cleaning.png'
import { NavLink,Link } from 'react-router-dom'

//props object is meant to be a read only object

const Header = (props) =>
(
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md navigation-clean main-nav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">
                <div>
                    <h1 class="text-center home-title">White Tiger Cleaning</h1>
                    <h6 class="text-center text-wrap">London &amp; South East Premier Commercial Cleaning Service</h6>
                </div>
            </Link>
            <button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-grow-1 justify-content-between ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <NavLink to='/' className="nav-link" exact>Home</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <NavLink to='/covid' className="nav-link">Covid-19</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Services</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">                                                                                                                                                                    
                            <NavLink to='/commercial' className="dropdown-item">Commercial</NavLink>  
                            <NavLink to='/carpet-floor' className="dropdown-item">Carpet Floor Cleaning</NavLink>                             
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Health &amp; Safety&nbsp;</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="safecontractor.html">Self Contractor</a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Testimonials</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <NavLink to='/clients' className="dropdown-item">Clients</NavLink>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="center-item"><img class="header-img" src={logo} alt="White Tiger Logo" /></div>
        </div>
    </nav>

);

export default Header;
```

The commercial component looks like this... I am just putting gibberish in the h3 for now.

```
import React from "react";

const Commercial = () => (
   <div>
     <h3>dsjdhsdsdsdsdsdsds</h3>
   </div>
);


export default Commercial;
```

Comment: do you element on html inspect?

Comment: you just have a typo here `<Route path='/commerical'`.

Comment: Oh my god... it was the typo! :O Damn it! sorry, I feel this post wasted time :(